# Need help theming elements - $classes not being output

Tags: theming

I'm having hard time theming text substitutions performed by my custom input filter.
I'm using this theme hook:

```
function ppf_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'ppf_link' => array(
      'template' => 'brand_product_link',
      'variables' => array(
        'title' => NULL,
        'nid' => NULL,
        'classes' => NULL,
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

accompanied by this code in my filter process callback:

```
return theme('ppf_link', array('nid' => $node_id, 'title' => $node_title, 'classes' =>  implode(' ', $classes)));
```

This basically works - i.e. I'm successfully printing out the `nid` and `title` variables in the `brand_product_link.tpl.php` file. I'm however unable to sneak in my custom classes in the `classes` variable. No matter what the classes array contains, Drupal will always render a single class `ppf-link` (which I assume is a default safe css class taken from my theme hook name). If I rename the variable to `my_classes` though - everything works ok.

Now, I'm not writing to get a fix for something that works, but to learn what I'm doing wrong when it does not. Is `classes` a protected variable? Should I use a `template_preprocess_ppf_link` function, if so - how should it look like?

Comment: What's the contents of $classes look like when you do this? Are you sure your filter process callback is getting executed before your theme hook?

Comment: I have moved on now to the working state, where I'm appending my classes to `classes_array`, which works. The contents of `$classes` was exactly as built it (when I checked it by `dpm()`'ing the variable), it's just that they wouldn't render out. As per the sequence: I am definitely calling theme hook as the last statement of the process callback.

Comment: Your theme hook sets "classes" to NULL so if it's being called last, it would blank out any other values you put in before that.

Comment: Yes, that's correct - but there is one invocation of the theme hook per one invocation of the tpl file, so NULLing the classes before that is more than desired. Each brand_product_link can have different classes, such as `product-link-nid-#`.